# How to use same variable name for several cases, then loop through same calculations for all cases?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Need to find a way to set up the same calculations, for a number of different cases that have the same variable names, but with different values.
In Python 2.7

I have a lot of cases where I set up busbars in different layouts, they then have different distances etc. I perform a lot of calculations with regards to forces and stress for all the cases, and I only want to write the math expressions once. I would like to loop through all cases, and perform the same calculations, but input the case specific variables while looping the cases. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you provide the code you've written so far to accomplish this?

Comment: How are the "case specific variables" stored, in the vector? Could you please provide a code example.

Comment: Use a loop. And functions.

Comment: `result = calculation(value)`

Comment: I do not have any code for this yet, I do not know how to solve it. I have the calculations for one case, but will now expand with several setups. And, I am not a computer person, I am trying to learn python to simplify and re- use calculations. I am an electrical engineer. So, I am very glad for all help. But can you please make example code, otherwise I am pretty much back to where I started. Googling your answers, trying to understand more.